# How to send a variable for PHP and make at the same time an html link to an element id?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

The question is difficult to make but the idea is very simple:

I want to send the variable 'count' via GET and at the same time go to the section media. In the page

```
http://page.org.mx/comunicados#media
```

I have tried this:

```
<a href= http://page.org.mx/comunicados#media?count=5">[sd]</a> 

<a href= http://page.org.mx/comunicados?count=5#media">[sd]</a>
```

But with out success. If i Insert the second manually it work.

Comment: The second one should work. If you 'insert it manually' and it works, it means that the link you create is _not_ exactly like you have manually (unless you do something weird with javascript and fragment identifiers).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax in incorrect for the link. You're missing a quote mark. This:

```
<a href= http://page.org.mx/comunicados?count=5#media">[sd]</a>
```

should be this:

```
<a href="http://page.org.mx/comunicados?count=5#media">[sd]</a>
```